# enumerateObjects failing on NSOrderedSet

Tags: swift, swift3

In Swift 2 I was able to do this:

```swift
let foo = NSOrderedSet()  
foo.enumerateObjects {  
    obj, idx, _ in  
    ...  
}
```

In Swift 3 I'm getting an error

```
Ambiguous use of 'enumerateObjects'
```

I'm not sure why the error is happening, or how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
let foo = NSOrderedSet(array: [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 1])

for (offset,element) in foo.enumerated() {
    print(offset)
    print(element)
}
```

You can also do it using forEach as follow:

```
foo.enumerated().forEach {
    print($0.offset)
    print($0.element)
}
```

Using enumerateObjects the correct syntax would be:

```
foo.enumerateObjects({
    (obj, idx, _)  in
    print(obj)
    print(idx)
})
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you have to `enumerate` on foo? aren't `OrderedSet`s enumeratable by default?

Comment: @Honey Sorry I just realised I didn't answer your question, I don't know what you meant by "enumeratable by default" (NSOrderedSet conforms to Sequence if that's what you mean)